# Java - NullPointerException in array?

Tags: java, arrays, linkedhashmap

I'm having some bother with a string array in java. I'm trying to output an inverseNewWords LinkedHashMap value to an output file, but I keep getting an NPE for the array. For some reason the first line doesn't seem to work.

```
System.out.println(inverseNewWords.get(codeIntegers[i]));
```

prints out the word fine, but this line:

```
System.out.println(newWTF[i]);
```

comes back as null.

```
newWTF[i] = inverseNewWords.get(codeIntegers[i]);
System.out.println(inverseNewWords.get(codeIntegers[i]));
System.out.println(newWTF[i]);
decodedWriter.write(newWTF[i]);
```

** EDIT ** 
Thanks for the quick replies, I've been working on this specific program throughout the night to get it submitted on time, and my head's cracked.
The string array was indeed initialized incorrectly, but now my main problem is showing it's face:

```
System.out.println(newWTF[i]);
decodedWriter.write(newWTF[i]);
```

the println statement correctly shows me each word in the array. However, the FileWriter isn't writing the same words to the file. (The Filewriter is being flushed and closed before the program ends)
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: 1) Make sure you initialized *EACH* of your arrays, 2) make sure the index points to a valid, allocated array element and, most important, 3) *STEP THROUGH THE CODE UNDER THE DEBUGGER* so you can actually *SEE* which variable is "null"!

Comment: What is the relationship between `codeIntegers` and `newWTF`?

Comment: @user3160821: Please attach the complete code , it's very hard to help you without it ! And use a try/catch clauses .

Comment: Put in try catch and print message in catch. why it behave like this.?

Comment: It would help to see the type declaration of newWTF[]

Comment: newWTF[i] = inverseNewWords.get(codeIntegers[i]).toString();  <= try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason why this line

```
System.out.println(newWTF[i]);
```

can throw NPE is that newWTF is null

Answer (score 0):

may help :

```
newWTF = new String[inverseNewWords.size()];
```